# Visual Studio C# add reference using library to linux

Tags: c#, linux, visual-studio, com, dotnet-linux

I added one SDK(.dll) to one project, through click righ -> add -> reference -> Browser -> look for the SDK in my local file explorer, then click Add and finnally Ok.

so, The question is that now I must add it but for a code directed for linux, I have the SDK for linux, its extension is .a

which is the way to add as a reference???, since the usual way only allows adding dll, tlb, olt, ocx, exe or manifest files

Comment: ```The NuGet Package Manager UI in Microsoft Visual Studio for Windows allows you to easily install, uninstall, and update NuGet packages in projects and solutions.``` I think that is only for windows packages

Comment: Your naming SDK(.dll) and your wording sound like its unmanaged code but the way you reference it sounds like it managed code. I'm a bit confused here. What is it?

Comment: let me explain it, I have one SDK, It's a alarm, so I have the sdk for windows and linux version, so I just want implement one code using c# to linux, But I want to add the linux sdk to the code, since obviously the windows version doesn't work on linux, you get it?